# How to create dual mode usb liux, bootable and startable directly from a Windows OS as virtual machine

Tags: usb-drive, live-usb, kali-linux

I have found many tutorials about create a bootable live Linux image, but I whant to create a very particular USB-linux pendrive that allows me

1. -to boot Linux image using the native harware if started at boot time (so not virtualized)
2. -to use the remaining space for storage purpose on Windows (so not formatted with ext filesystem)
3. -to start as virtualized OS if I try to start it from another already started OS eg Windows

The distro that I have choosen for the installation on the pendrive is Kali, but I don't know how to do all this.

Someone could help me? Thanks

Comment: using this you could possibly do it, the main problem is getting your linux partition inside a vhdd for virtualbox http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-12/use-a-real-windows-7-partition-in-virtualbox-kvm-vmware-player-u.html

Answer (score 0):

Gilsham basically answered your question, as long as you are using VirtualBox.

To type it out here:

1. Find your drive identifier and absolute path:

Under Linux check out /dev/sd* or via parted or GParted

Under Windows open HDD manager [ Win+R "mmc" -> add "disk management" /or "Computer management" and open "disk management" ]

1. create a vmdk file via virualbox management tools:
   `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename yourChosenMachineNamePath.vmdk -rawdisk <disk absolute path>`
2. might have to use sudo
3. create a virtual machine in VirtualBox or add your newly created linkfile as a storage file to an existing VM
4. Boot the VM.

   - Mind you: Windows Vista/7/8 might get fairly pissed and you'll have to re-activate it every time you switch it to and from a VM, because the HW signature would change and Windows really, really don't like this.
   - As for linux systems: Depending on your bootloader settings you might be required to re-install / fix GUI and a few other things.
   - - e.g.: I had trouble installing Oracle Linux on a server for testing purposes. Optical drive was faulty, no network and it's not so easy to create Live Oracle Linux USB disk. So I made Persistent Ubuntu, added VirtualBox and Oracle Linux ISO, installed Oracle Linux via VirtualBox and after booting into the system I had to re-install Gnome2, because for some reason it wouldn't work.

Additional notes:

- If you want to have two or more partitions on the usb drive, then before beginning of the whole process prepare the partitions [ e.g.: GParted ] . Since we are talking about multi-partition USB, the parameter for VBoxManage createrawvmdk would be /dev/sd?# where ? is the a/b/c/... of your device and # is the number of the partition. I suggest formatting the other partition to NTFS. Most linux distros have no problem CRUDing NTFS and it has support for large files.
- If you want to create this live-usb via some Live USB creator, then make sure that the target is the exact partition that you want to have the data on and create the data-transfer partition afterwards. To avoid trouble leave some space between the partitions. I generally use 1 MB. I know, that it's a lot, but on a >4 GB usb drive it doesn't matter as much and I actually don't have to worry, when applying this process under Win, about overlapping partitions [ had this problem twice in my life and I don't ever want to have it again ]